# How to exclude 0 when using RandBetween?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially, I want to have a random + or - so I'm using a RandBetween(-1,1). However, when the value is value is zero, I obviously get the same number I started off with. Is there a way to exclude the zero?

Thanks in advance!

Excel Example:
=J1+(J1*RAND()*RANDBETWEEN(-1,1)*0.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select 1 or -1 with 50% probability:

```
=IF(RAND()<0.5, 1, -1)
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

For fun, here is a different solution which uses `RandBetween`:

```
=(-1)^RANDBETWEEN(0,1)
```